# thumbnail order in a carrousel playlist

Tags: php, javascript, video, thumbnails, playlist

we setup a carrousel playlist with thumbnails for a video player.
the system looks into a thumbnail folder and display all thumbs in the carrousel. each thumb can launch is own video.
everything works great except the fact that i cannot order my thumbnails. I named them : 00mythumb.jpg, 01mythumb.jpg etc... and I'm looking for a way to order them in the carrousel.

my code is as follow :

```
 <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
 <?php
 $i = 0;
 $dir = opendir('./gallery/pics');
 while ($file = @readdir($dir)) {
 //Récupération de l'extension du fichier
 $extension=substr(strrchr($file,'.'),1);
 if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){
    $i++;
    //Suppression de l'extension du fichier
    $pos = strpos($file, '.');
    $file = substr($file, 0, $pos);
    //Inscription de la ligne en HTML
    echo '<li><a onclick="jwplayer().load(\'./gallery/video/'. $file. '.mp4\')"><imag src="./gallery/pics/'. $file. '.jpg" width="164" height="95" alt=""/></a></li>';
}
```

}
?>

any help would be appreciated.
thank you very much and apologies for my bad english.
ps : i replaced img by imag because stack overflow do not allowed me to put img tag inside the code

Answer (score 3):

```
<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
<?php
 $i = 0;
 $dir = opendir('./gallery/pics');
 $files = array();
 while ($file = @readdir($dir)) {
      $files[] = $file;
 }
 sort($files);
 foreach($files as $file) {
   //Récupération de l'extension du fichier
   $extension=substr(strrchr($file,'.'),1);
   if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){
      //Suppression de l'extension du fichier
      $pos = strpos($file, '.');
      $file = substr($file, 0, $pos);
      //Inscription de la ligne en HTML
      echo '<li><a onclick="jwplayer().load(\'./gallery/video/'. $file. '.mp4\')"><imag src="./gallery/pics/'. $file. '.jpg" width="164" height="95" alt=""/></a></li>';
   }
 }
```

Comment: may I name my picture as i want ? or should I put them in alpha numeric order ?

Comment: ok Ive just tested and it work perfect... thanks for your help :-)